# Variable Google Fonts not Applying Valid CSS Properties

Tags: html, css, fonts, google-font-api, variable-fonts

I am learning how to use variable Google fonts and wrote this HTML:

```
<h1>This heading should be condensed.</h1>
```

with the following CSS:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Anybody:wdth,wght@50..200,100..700&display=swap');

h1 {
  font-family: 'Anybody';
  font-weight: 900;
  font-stretch: 50%;
}
```

The font 'Anybody' supports width axis (https://fonts.google.com/knowledge/using_type/styling_type_on_the_web_with_variable_fonts) so why isn't the text condensed?

A demo on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yr4h8wg1/

Comment: Are you seeing text formatted with the Anybody font and 900 weight, but just the wrong width?

Comment: @PeterConstable I have added a demo on JSFiddle. The font doesn't even get applied in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `@import` URL, you specified a wdth range of 50..200. But it appears the Anybody font only supports a wdth range of 50..150 — see https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Anybody/tester. In your JSFiddle demo, change the "200" to "150" and it works.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Anybody:wdth,wght@50..150,100..900&display=swap');
```

Comment: Thanks Peter. I didn't know about the Type Tester in Google fonts. I will try it with other fonts now. :)

Comment: Is it possible to download and install variable fonts locally? The project I am working on will always be on my local machine and I just prefer installing those fonts locally.

Comment: If you go to https://fonts.google.com/?vfonly=true and click into any of the variable fonts they have, then at the top right of the page click "Download family", you'll get download that contains the variable font as well as static (non-variable) fonts for the named instances.

Answer (score 0):

Providing  a font-weight of 900, and a font-stretch of 50%:

https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Anybody:wdth,wght@50,900&display=swap